# How to intercept "go" button on Android number soft keypad for web app with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, android, html, jquery, web-applications

Thank you in advance for your time!

In my web application, I have a number input that is part of a form submitted with AJAX and jQuery.  The user enters a number (phone number in this case) and hits the "share" button, which is not an html submit button but a div that has an event listener.

When Android users click the number input, the number soft keypad is displayed.  This keypad has a "go" button.  When users click the "go" button, nothing happens.  To submit the form, users must click the back button to hide the soft keypad and click the "share" button on the web page.  This has caused confusion with several users.

Can I intercept the click on the "go" button from the soft keypad and use that to trigger my AJAX request?

Here is a redacted screenshot.  The "share" button is behind the number soft keypad, which adds to user confusion:

[image]

Here's a snippet of the code:

**HTML**

```
<label>Recipient Phone Number<br>
<small>Numbers only.  Enter country code for international.</small>
<input type="number" step='1' id="shareNumber"></label>
<div id="sendShare">Share</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#container').on('click','#sendShare',function(event){
    event.preventDefault;
    var phoneNumber = $('#shareNumber').val();
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
            phoneNumber: phoneNumber
            },
        success: function(data) {
            // do stuff
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android 'Go' button is used in input elements to submit their parent `form`. As you have no form wrapping your input, nothing appears to happen.

Instead of listening specifically for the 'Go' button all you need to do is wrap the input in a `form` element and hook your AJAX code to the `submit` event of that form.

Note in the following example that I change the `#sendShare` element to a `button` so that it too submits the `form` element, but without needing to add any additional JS code.

```html
<form id="yourForm">
  <label>Recipient Phone Number<br>
    <small>Numbers only.  Enter country code for international.</small>
    <input type="number" step='1' id="shareNumber" />
  </label>
  <button type="submit" id="sendShare">Share</button>
</form>
```

```js
$('#container').on('submit', '#yourForm', e => {
  e.preventDefault;
  var phoneNumber = $('#shareNumber').val();
  
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: { phoneNumber: phoneNumber },
    success: function(data) {
      // do stuff
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the speedy response.  I had considered using form elements, but I've had bad experiences in the past attaching a listener to the submit event.  I purposely try to avoid it, but in this case, it might be the way to go.  If I use this approach, I will mark your answer as correct.  Again, I appreciate your help immensely.

Comment: Attaching to the `submit` event handler is best practice and should always be used with `form` tags. And no problem, hope the answer helps :)

Comment: Accepted answer.  Thanks